# Есть ли ошибки в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, грамматика, стилистика, семантика

Есть ли в этом предложении  ошибки – смысловые, грамматические, стилистические или пунктуационные?

***Рост цен** на канцтовары за 10 месяцев текущего года был значительно выше **уровня инфляции** – **7,2% и 5,3% соответственно**.*

Примечание. В предложении использована присоединительная конструкция, обособленная тире. Грамматического  согласования присоединительной  и основной части  в этом случае не требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По определению **уровень инфляции** показывает, на сколько процентов в среднем выросли цены за рассматриваемый период. Рост цен на канцтовары **за 10 месяцев** определяет *темп роста цен* по выбранной категории товаров в течение рассматриваемого периода времени. Сравнение *темпа роста цен* с *уровнем инфляции* абсолютно корректно.

[image: Финансовая математика]

P.S. Многие путают различные значения слова **рост**, поэтому уместно будет сослаться на словарь Кузнецова и подчеркнуть, что в данном случае речь идёт о значении 1, а не 2.

> **РОСТ**, -а (-у); м.
> **1**. к Расти. Р. зубов, волос. Р. населения. Р.
> доходов, жизненного уровня трудящихся. Р. профессионального
> мастерства. Быстрый, бурный, замедленный р. Время бурного роста трав.
> Остановить р. цен. Темпы роста. Остановиться в росте (перестать
> расти). Трава пошла в р. (начала расти).
> **2**. Высота человека,
> животного. Паренёк высокого, среднего роста. Мал ростом кто-л. Мужичок
> ростом с ноготок. У него р. около двух метров. Что-л. в р. человека, в
> человеческий рост (о высоте каких-л. предметов). Строиться,
> становиться по росту (в последовательности от самого высокого к самому
> низкому). Встать, стоять во весь (в полный) р. (выпрямившись). Сделать
> фотографию в полный р. (с изображением всей фигуры). Платье у тебя не
> по росту (не подходит по длине рукавов, брюк, юбки и т.п.). Какой у
> тебя р.?

Comment: *Многие путают различные значения слова рост,* - ну вы совсем уже все запутали. У себя посмотрите,  *Рост цен определяет **темп*** - т.е. рост (в первом кузнецовском значении, заметьте!) это именно изменение. А уровень - это величина фиксированная. Вот и все. Это просто некоторые путают **значение** величины с **изменением**  этого значения.

Comment: Кстати говоря, вот это тоже совершенно неверно: *по определению уровень инфляции показывает*. То есть он сожет что-то там показать в плане, но никак не по определению. Давайте все-то в экономических вопросах пользоваться более адекватными определениями.  Инфляцией, если упрощенно, называется  общий рост денежной массы, как правило не обеспеченной рынком товара.

Comment: @behemothus Добавил цитату из первого попавшегося учебника по финансовой математике. Спорить в упрощённых терминах "прироста денежной массы" не стану — я не сомневаюсь, что фразу можно сформулировать в этих или ещё в каких-нибудь других терминах, но первоначальная фраза от этого не станет менее корректной.

Comment: Не знаю, где вы этот учебник нашли, но путать темп и уровень - это край. И дело не в том, что можно сформулировать в правильных терминах, дело в том, что фраза изначально безнадежна. Как её ни переформулируй.

Answer (score 0):

Во фразе есть как минимум одна смысловая ошибка. "Рост цен" и "уровень инфляции" - две совершенно несопоставимых категории. Этот факт делает бессмысленным поиск других, чисто лингвистических ошибок.

Если заменить экономические показатели, в которых многие реально путаются, на что-то более понятное, получим нечто вроде ***"Рост Васи за последний год значительно выше уровня успеваемости Пети по русскому языку - 10% и 5% соответственно."***

Ничего глаз не режет? Подскажу. ***Рост*** сравнивается с ***уровнем***. Это бессмыслица, которая видна, простите, невооруженным взглядом.

Answer (score 0):

**Это мой вопрос-комментарий  к участнику grizzly**

**Пожалуйста,** проверьте мои рассуждения на тему «корректно ли рост сравнивать с уровнем».

**Определение**

Главным показателем инфляции выступает **темп (или уровень) инфляции** (rate of inflation), который рассчитывается как процентное отношение **разницы уровней цен текущего и предыдущего года к уровню цен предыдущего года**: (Р2 – Р1/Р1)×100℅.
Р1  – общий уровень цен предыдущего года, Р2  – общий уровень цен текущего года.  http://www.ereport.ru/articles/macro/macro14.htm

Значит, **УРОВЕНЬ (темп) инфляции – это РОСТ общего уровня цен за текущий период**.

В приведенном примере за 10 месяцев рост общего уровня цен (уровень инфляции) – 5,3℅, а рост цен  на канцтовары оказался выше – 7,2℅. Таким образом, мы сравниваем **РОСТ** общего уровня цен (**УРОВЕНЬ инфляции**) с **РОСТОМ** цен в отдельной отрасли, что вполне **корректно**.

Comment: Sharon, что касается корректности сравнения уровня инфляции с ростом цен в отдельной отрасли, Ваше понимание в принципе верно, но оно требует небольшой корректировки в деталях. Дело в том, что под уровнем инфляции всегда понимают относительный **годовой** прирост цен. Для оценки инфляции за меньший период применяют другие показатели (напр., "индекс потребительских цен"). Либо на основании данных за текущий период делают прогноза годового уровня инфляции (что прямо оговаривается). Это меня немного смущает и в первоначальной фразе, но без контекста я не могу утверждать, что там есть ошибка.

Comment: В последнем абзаце у Вас дважды употреблён термин "уровень инфляции". Во втором случае был выбран правильный падеж, а в первом я поправил.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. В СМИ я видела информацию о расчете уровня инфляции по месяцам https://www.statbureau.org/ru/russia/inflation-tables

Comment: Ок, значит в этих деталях у меня пробелы. Тогда у Вас всё верно, а в обсуждаемой фразе либо не совсем аккуратно, либо должны быть оговорки в окружающем контексте.

Comment: Аккуратнее было бы так: "За 10 месяцев текущего года рост цен на канцтовары был значительно выше уровня инфляции – 7,2% и 5,3% соответственно" или так: "Рост цен на канцтовары за 10 месяцев текущего года был значительно выше уровня инфляции за тот же период – 7,2% и 5,3% соответственно".

Comment: Да, я как раз тоже подумала о втором варианте, он мне нравится больше: сначала обозначен предмет, а потом собщение о нем.

Answer (score 0):

Без ошибок первых трёх видов здесь не обошлось. Смесь стилистической и грамматической ошибок ведет к ошибке смысловой. "Соответствие" величин выражено недопустимым образом: соотносимые сущности разбросаны по предложению и находятся в разных падежах. Расшифровать смысл можно только неграмматическим путем, а именно найти среди слов предложения ровно две сущности и два числа, что в сочетании с указанием "выше" позволяет выявить "соответствие". Пунктуационой же ошибки нет: тире направлено на исправление совокупной "тройственной" ошибки, но эта цель не достигается. Исправить предложение можно разве что добавлением после имеющегося тире дополнительного разъяснения (тире не позволяет его опустить):

> Рост цен на канцтовары за 10 месяцев текущего года был значительно
> выше уровня инфляции – *рост цен и уровень инфляции составили* 7,2% и
> 5,3% соответственно.

Comment: Alex_ander, наш язык устроен так, что семантику речи мы воспринимваем непосредственно, а не через анализ грамматических конструкций. Мы же не роботы, а люди. Наше сознание четко улавливает КЛЮЧЕВУЮ информацию: ДВА предмета сравнения и ДВЕ цифры. А вот в вашем варианте они повторяются дважды (получается ЧЕТЫРЕ предмета), а цифры всего ДВЕ. Наше бедное сознание запутается в  такой фразе, так что придется ее перечитать, чтобы понять. Если бы наш язык строился по таким механическим законам,  мы бы думали и говорили  очень-очень медленно. Но, к счастью, научились эффективно считывать информацию.

Comment: И по поводу ошибок, у нас же строгая их классификация. Назовите, в чем заключается нарушение грамматики и в чем нарушение стиля. Эти ошибки четко классифицируются, надо указать конкретные признаки, желательно по Розенталю и хотя бы по какому-то источнику. Грамматика идет в первую очередь. Простое предложение, осложненное присоединительным оборотом. В чем там нарушение? И т.д. В Нацкорпусе такая форма (обособление цифровой информации скобками или тире) применяется часто.

Comment: Нарушение грамматики заключается в _неверных падежах_. Прежде всего, по падежам различаются вторая из сопоставляемых сущностей и её величина (родительный и именительный). Это является следствием употребления оборота "А и В соответственно" (в его рамках падежи всегда совпадают, здесь величины в именительном). _Стилистическую_ ошибку здесь трудно отделить от грамматической (это скорее дипломатичное наименование грамматической), но можно сказать и так: не следовало упротреблять "соответственно" в сочетании с первой частью предложения; правильно было бы так:

Comment: _Рост цен на канцтовары за 10 месяцев текущего года был значительно выше уровня инфляции – 7,2% **против** 5,3%._ Здесь и с падежами порядок.

Comment: Падежи восприятию речи нисколько не мешают, а вот слово "против" там не месте, оно не из этой темы и цепляет слух. Вы отказываетесь от стандартной  и всем понятнй формулировки со словом "соответственно" по совершенно необоснованным  причинам.

Comment: "Против" это вполне стандартный элемент для таких выражений. Как и "соответственно", это элемент технического стиля. Вот первое попавшееся выражение (пусть и от журналистов): _По подсчетам ТАСС, если учитывать только случаи, когда коронавирус стал основной причиной смерти, показатель будет равен 2,9% против 2,5% в мае..._ https://tass.ru/obschestvo/9148787 Для каждого из этих слов - свой уместный контекст.

Comment: Ещё пример: _Навальный больше вдохновляет людей в средней возрастной группе 40-54 лет, где он даже обошел Путина (6% против 5%)._